# Override HTTP header's default settings (X-FRAME-OPTIONS)

Tags: laravel, http-headers, laravel-4, x-frame-options

I'm working with the dev version of Laravel (4.1.*) and there is a new default configuration that I don't want : `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`

For the moment I disable it [by deleting one line in `Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/FrameGuard.php#L40)

I'm looking for a better solution. I've try in the filtre.php file :

```
App::after(function($request, $response) {
   $response->header('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-ALL');
});
```

But it just adds the option (`X-Frame-Options:ALLOW-ALL, SAMEORIGIN`), whereas I need an override.

Comment: Anyone arriving here using laravel 4.2 and wanting to limit X-Frame-Options header back to the 'old' behaviour (pre-4.2): edit ```app/filters.php``` and add the following line in the ```App::after()``` filter: ```$response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN', true);```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Laravel doesn't provide any configuration to disable this functionality.

According to [Taylor Otwell](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1725#issuecomment-27603001), the only way to bypass it is by adding the following line into the start file:

```
App::forgetMiddleware('Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard');
```

The dirty solution is to comment the [guilty line](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/FrameGuard.php#L40):

```
$response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN', false);
```

---

**Edit (Jan 29th 2014)**: new info from Taylor Otwell [on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1725#issuecomment-33535578) about next Laravel's policy.

> Removing this by default in 4.2. Should be in an after filter - will leave FrameGuard class so people can add the middleware manually if they want.

Comment: Good to have it here also :)
Here is detailed topic also: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=64869

Comment: so is this App::forgetMiddleware('Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard'); still useful in 4.2 ?

Comment: @ngakak I didn't test Laravel 4 yet, but as far as I understand Taylor Otwell's words, is that Laravel 4 will have no X-FRAME-OPTIONS value defined In default header anymore. Do you have a X-FRAME-OPTIONS problem?

Comment: Is there also a solution for laravel 5?

Comment: Is there a solution is 5.3 as I am having this issue now and cant find any info on it besides the above.

Comment: Any idea to do it with php cURL?

Answer (score 5):

The third parameter of the [`header`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0d7f0a3a9ace7f6874914731e25a3330fa1834ab/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php#L24) method should serve your needs.

Comment: It should work except if the FrameGuard file is called at the end of the application, and it's the case. I found an [issue request on Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1725) about this problem.