# Web site not showing in iframe

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, canvas

Why does my website build using laravel 4 shows blank page in facebook canvas?

i have this route

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@getIndex');
```

I have put `https://www.mysite.com/canvas/` in facebook app settings

when i visit the link it shows me the content of my site but in my facebook canvas it is not showing. Only a blank page. Why is this happening? what could be the problem?

Comment: The initial load of your app into the FB iframe happens via a POST request, not GET.

Comment: i tried changing it to post but still now working

Comment: Do you have a valid SSL certificate for your domain? What do your server’s log files say?

Comment: Yes i have a valid ssl. the site was first build in CodeIgniter then I change it to Laravel 4 then this problem happens

Comment: found the problem why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293116/override-http-headers-default-settings-x-frame-options

Comment: hey dude you were right about post

Comment: how do i change this to GET?

Comment: You don’t. Facebook loads apps by POSTing an HTML form targeted at the iframe for the initial loading of your app, there is nothing you can change about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following CBroe answer
Facebook makes a POST request so try changing your code to:

```
Route::post('/','HomeController@getIndex');
```

That should do the trick.